# Print unicode character in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode

How can I print unicode strings within Python 3?

```
myString = 'My unicode character: \ufffd'
print(myString)
```

The Output should be: "My unicode character: ü"

> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line
>   19, in encode return
>   codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in
>   position 22: character maps to

I have read lots of articles about this on Stack Exchange, but non of the answers worked.

Please help. I am really curious how to solve this really simple looking example! Thans very much in advance!

Comment: Side note: I don't know why you're expecting U+FFFD, the replacement character "�" to print ü.

Comment: BTW, `\ufffd` is _not_ `ü`. The codepoint for LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS is `\u00fc`, which is `b'\xc3\xbc'` in the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing this using Windows command line.

```
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

You can try to run above command first before running `python3`. It will set the console encoder to utf-8 that can represent your data.