# Why does write reject xlrd output on Anaconda command prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, xlrd

I am working on a Windows computer.

A script extracts data (numbers and strings) from an Excel spreadsheet, manipulates it, and outputs it using `write`. It worked fine until I started applying it to something with Unicode characters, at which point I got

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0159' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried

```
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

in the hope that what [would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915296/print-unicode-character-in-python-3) for `print` would work for `write`, but it didn't.

Here is the code (after I removed everything I thought was extraneous).

```
class listing:
    def __init__(self,input8):
        self.personname=input8
    def listing_string(self):
        return self.personname+'\n'

import xlrd
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
myfile = open('test', 'w')
for y in range(worksheet.nrows-1):
    person=worksheet.cell(y+1,15).value
    myListing=listing(person)
    myfile.write( myListing.listing_string() )
myfile.close()
```